# Kubernetes unknown field "volumes"

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a simple nginx in kubernetes using hostvolumes. I use the next **yaml**:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webserver
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: hostvol
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
    volumes:
    - name: hostvol
      hostPath:
        path: /home/docker/vol
```

When I deploy it `kubectl create -f webserver.yaml`, it throws the next error:

```
error: error validating "webserver.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template): unknown field "volumes" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodTemplateSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: Have you solved this error? I got them same error.

Comment: Yes, try checking your identation.

Comment: Ok, I solved this, first I have made a mistake of indentation, second there are so many typos, it's case sensitive. Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I believe you have the wrong indentation. The `volumes` key should be at the same level as `containers`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webserver
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: hostvol
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: hostvol
        hostPath:
          path: /home/docker/vol
```

Look at [this wordpress example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/#deploy-wordpress) from the documentation to see how it's done.